# Sharepoint GetListItems returns no rows

Tags: java, sharepoint, soap, webservice-client

I have a jax ws client to call GetListItems given a list name and view name and it all works fine locally on my windows 7 machine. However when I deploy to my Linux server the same service return zero rows. There are no exceptions and I have compare the soap request for both machines and it the same

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: It returns a 200 response with an item count=0

Answer (score 0):

Have you authenticated with the SharePoint site? There is an excellent writeup on SharePoint ajax authentication here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/how-to-authenticate-user-in-sharepoint-online-using-javascript

From the previous link, here is the code to authenticate:

```
var soapDataString = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
  <soap:Body> \
    <Login xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
      <username>username</username> \
      <password>password</password> \
    </Login> \
  </soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>"

// Call web service
$.ajax({
  url: "http://mywebsitename:2355/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "xml",
  data: soapDataString,
  success: resultsFeedback,
  contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});

function resultsFeedback(xData, status) {
   alert(xData);
   alert(status);
}
```